# how to upload file to mysql table using path in yii

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I try to upload a file to MySQL table and it does not work.
here what i write:

view:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'doc_ordered_recieved'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'doc_ordered_recieved'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'doc_ordered_recieved'); ?>
</div>
```

model:
i add this attribute:

```
public $doc_ordered_recieved;
```

and this rulse:

```
array('doc_ordered_recieved','file','types'=>'pdf', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'on'=>'update'),
```

controllers:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Orders;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Orders']))
        {

            $model->attributes=$_POST['Orders'];
            $model->doc_ordered_recieved=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'doc_ordered_recieved');
            if($model->save())
            {
                $doc_ordered_recieved->saveAs('http://localhost/files');
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->oid));
            }
        }
    $this->render('create',array('model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

please help me i don't know why its not work????

thanks you all
eliya

Comment: Have you used `enctype` in your view form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to change the rule to add create scenario:

```
array('doc_ordered_recieved','file','types'=>'pdf', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'on'=>'insert,update'),
```

and in your create action from your controller you need to do this:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Orders;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Orders']))
    {

        $model->attributes=$_POST['Orders'];
        $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'doc_ordered_recieved');
        if($model->save())
        {
            if(!empty($uploadedFile))  // check if uploaded file is set or not
            {

                if($model->image == null || empty($model->image)){
                    $rnd = rand(0,9999);// generate random number between 0-9999
                    $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";
                    $model->image = $fileName;
                }
                $uploadedFile->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__)..'/files/'. $model->doc_ordered_recieved);
                // redirect to success page
            }
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->oid));
        }
    }
        $this->render('create',array('model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: hi thank you very much. i did what you ask me for but it still give me this message "Doc Ordered Recieved cannot be blank." can you help me please????

Comment: @eli probably in model rules you have this: `array('doc_ordered_recieved','required')` this can be the cause you try to save model with out image...

Comment: @eli other method to pass the model validation and save the data is to use: `$model->save(false)` no `$model->save()`

Comment: hi in the model this is what i have array('doc_ordered_recieved','required') but i tryed to save it with pdf file ofcourse please help thanks by the way the table is define varchar for the doc_ordered_recieved is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at your code I can see that you need to change your file path from

```
$doc_ordered_recieved->saveAs('http://localhost/files');
```

to

```
$doc_ordered_recieved->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'path/to/localFile');
```

Also, you should provide more information about your model.